# How to alter existing page of a node that is Organic Group and add Two links above

Tags: 7, organic-groups, javascript

i am using Drupal 7 with og support and also the og corresponding modules (og, entityreference, services_menu) inside DrupalGap.

As can be seen from the picture i want to add some links(drawed in red color) on top of the display of an Organic Group. I want the subscribe/unsubscribe button AND the navigation buttons above.

[image: Default display of an Organic Group inside drupalgap]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a [Custom DrupalGap Block](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Blocks/Create_a_Custom_Block)
2. Place it above the `title` block within the `region` configuration of the `settings.js` file
3. Use a [List Widget](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Widgets/List_Widget) and some CSS to render your buttons above the title

Comment: @tyler.frankestein  
1. I agree that this is the approach. Thanks for pointing the direction to it.  
2. i dont think that this will work since i only need this menu to show up in Organic Groups nodes. So menu must carry some id of the specific group. Members must be of the specific groups and Posts also of the specific group. So i think it must not be something static and created in 'settings.js'

Comment: To follow up, we chatted about a more dynamic solution to this problem here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/236906/10645